# Attempting to assign values to uint32_t* causes hang in OpenCL kernel

Tags: c, opencl

I am trying to generate public keys from private keys using OpenCL, but in one of the ecc functions, attempting to change the values in an `uint32_t*` causes the program to hang.  I have tracked the problem to this function (don't worry about what it does):

```
#define uint32_t uint
#define uint64_t ulong

static void secp256k1_fe_sqr_inner(uint32_t *r, const uint32_t *a) {
    uint64_t c, d;
    uint64_t u0, u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6, u7, u8;
    uint32_t t9, t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7;
    const uint32_t M = 0x3FFFFFFUL, R0 = 0x3D10UL, R1 = 0x400UL;

    d  = (uint64_t)(a[0]*2) * a[9]
       + (uint64_t)(a[1]*2) * a[8]
       + (uint64_t)(a[2]*2) * a[7]
       + (uint64_t)(a[3]*2) * a[6]
       + (uint64_t)(a[4]*2) * a[5];
    t9 = d & M; d >>= 26;
    c  = (uint64_t)a[0] * a[0];
    d += (uint64_t)(a[1]*2) * a[9]
       + (uint64_t)(a[2]*2) * a[8]
       + (uint64_t)(a[3]*2) * a[7]
       + (uint64_t)(a[4]*2) * a[6]
       + (uint64_t)a[5] * a[5];
    u0 = d & M; d >>= 26; c += u0 * R0;
    t0 = c & M; c >>= 26; c += u0 * R1;
    c += (uint64_t)(a[0]*2) * a[1];
    d += (uint64_t)(a[2]*2) * a[9]
       + (uint64_t)(a[3]*2) * a[8]
       + (uint64_t)(a[4]*2) * a[7]
       + (uint64_t)(a[5]*2) * a[6];
    u1 = d & M; d >>= 26; c += u1 * R0;
    t1 = c & M; c >>= 26; c += u1 * R1;
    c += (uint64_t)(a[0]*2) * a[2]
       + (uint64_t)a[1] * a[1];
    d += (uint64_t)(a[3]*2) * a[9]
       + (uint64_t)(a[4]*2) * a[8]
       + (uint64_t)(a[5]*2) * a[7]
       + (uint64_t)a[6] * a[6];
    u2 = d & M; d >>= 26; c += u2 * R0;
    t2 = c & M; c >>= 26; c += u2 * R1;
    c += (uint64_t)(a[0]*2) * a[3]
       + (uint64_t)(a[1]*2) * a[2];
    d += (uint64_t)(a[4]*2) * a[9]
       + (uint64_t)(a[5]*2) * a[8]
       + (uint64_t)(a[6]*2) * a[7];
    u3 = d & M; d >>= 26; c += u3 * R0;
    t3 = c & M; c >>= 26; c += u3 * R1;
    c += (uint64_t)(a[0]*2) * a[4]
       + (uint64_t)(a[1]*2) * a[3]
       + (uint64_t)a[2] * a[2];
    d += (uint64_t)(a[5]*2) * a[9]
       + (uint64_t)(a[6]*2) * a[8]
       + (uint64_t)a[7] * a[7];
    u4 = d & M; d >>= 26; c += u4 * R0;
    t4 = c & M; c >>= 26; c += u4 * R1;
    c += (uint64_t)(a[0]*2) * a[5]
       + (uint64_t)(a[1]*2) * a[4]
       + (uint64_t)(a[2]*2) * a[3];
    d += (uint64_t)(a[6]*2) * a[9]
       + (uint64_t)(a[7]*2) * a[8];
    u5 = d & M; d >>= 26; c += u5 * R0;
    t5 = c & M; c >>= 26; c += u5 * R1;
    c += (uint64_t)(a[0]*2) * a[6]
       + (uint64_t)(a[1]*2) * a[5]
       + (uint64_t)(a[2]*2) * a[4]
       + (uint64_t)a[3] * a[3];
    d += (uint64_t)(a[7]*2) * a[9]
       + (uint64_t)a[8] * a[8];
    u6 = d & M; d >>= 26; c += u6 * R0;
    t6 = c & M; c >>= 26; c += u6 * R1;
    c += (uint64_t)(a[0]*2) * a[7]
       + (uint64_t)(a[1]*2) * a[6]
       + (uint64_t)(a[2]*2) * a[5]
       + (uint64_t)(a[3]*2) * a[4];
    d += (uint64_t)(a[8]*2) * a[9];
    u7 = d & M; d >>= 26; c += u7 * R0;
    t7 = c & M; c >>= 26; c += u7 * R1;
    c += (uint64_t)(a[0]*2) * a[8]
       + (uint64_t)(a[1]*2) * a[7]
       + (uint64_t)(a[2]*2) * a[6]
       + (uint64_t)(a[3]*2) * a[5]
       + (uint64_t)a[4] * a[4];
    d += (uint64_t)a[9] * a[9];
    u8 = d & M; d >>= 26; c += u8 * R0;
    -->r[3] = t3;
    r[4] = t4;
    r[5] = t5;
    r[6] = t6;
    r[7] = t7;
    r[8] = c & M; c >>= 26; c += u8 * R1;
    c   += d * R0 + t9;
    r[9] = c & (M >> 4); c >>= 22; c += d * (R1 << 4);
    d    = c * (R0 >> 4) + t0;
    r[0] = d & M; d >>= 26;
    d   += c * (R1 >> 4) + t1;
    r[1] = d & M; d >>= 26;
    d   += t2;
    r[2] = d;
}
```

`r` is originally a `uint32_t` array of size 10. The problem starts at the arrow (near the bottom), where it is trying to set `r[3] = t3`.  The kernel is built and runs, but just hangs at this point.  GPU-Z says there is no GPU load and temps are like at idle, even though the fans are going crazy.

I tried creating a `uint32_t temp[10]` and setting the values there just the same as with `r`, and then setting `r = temp`.  This prevents the hang, but the end result of the computation is incorrect (it produces the same output for any input). I really don't understand what the problem is.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to compile, with the OpenCL that comes with CUDA SDK 12.2. I also installed Intel's oneAPI to be able to run OpenCL code on the CPU. I'm trying to run this on a Windows 10 machine with Intel processor and 3080 mobile GPU.  I also have the "`-cl-std=CL1.2`" option set in `clBuildProgram`.

Comment: I don’t see any memory space annotations on your pointers. Are you perhaps attempting to assign to `global` memory via a pointer to `private`? That won’t work. I recommend annotating *all* pointers with memory types, as the rules for which memory space is used implicitly depends on context and isn’t necessarily obvious and thus error prone.

Comment: You should indeed compute the key into a local array and use the appropriate API to copy the resulting array back to userland.

Comment: did you solve the issue. i'm having problems with the same secp256k1 code but in a different function and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Wild guess:  `r` isn't (always) a sufficiently well-aligned pointer, and therefore undefined behavior is being invoked when you dereference it.  You might put something like  `assert((((uintptr_t)r)%sizeof(uint32))==0);` at the top of the function so that if that is what's happening, it will be made obvious (and maybe do the same thing for `a`, just for completeness)

Comment: You cannot assign the content of an array by the assignment `r = temp;`. This is C, you need to copy each element individually, or use for example `memcpy()`. -- What happens if you assign constants to `r`, like `r[3] = 33;`?

Comment: @rrs @JeremyFriesner @thebusybee I strongly suspect you're all on the wrong track here, and it really is caused by trying to cast pointers between memory spaces. Unfortunately no calling code has been made available in the question; if you're literally using the same code, @rrs, and @MrPuzzler appears to have abandoned the question, perhaps you could edit the question to include the actual `kernel` function that calls this helper function, then I can actually point out the specific issue, because the code provided is strictly speaking not wrong as far as I can see, but probably called wrong.

Comment: To be abundantly clear, neither `uint32_t *r` nor `const uint32_t *a` are annotated with any of `global`, `private`, `local`, or `constant`. I consider this a significant code smell as it's an endless source of bugs like this. I believe in this case, they both default to `private`. If the pointer you're passing as `r` when calling `secp256k1_fe_sqr_inner` from the kernel function does not point to private memory, you'll get undefined behaviour, which can manifest as described in the question.

Comment: in my case, the issue were several loops. once i unrolled them by hand it worked